# Output is blank when running the program

Tags: output

I am currently working on a project via my visual studio 2019 software. i have the correct coding and the design for the project. however, whenever i run the program, it shows that there are no issues at all but I do not receive an output. my txtbox or lstbox (depending on the project) is blank and there are no error messages. I have a total of 6 projects due and all 6 projects are showing the same result. i am new to this and have minimal knowledge.

Comment: Are you working on Python GUI? Have you called the function at last? Please share a sample code so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: I am working on visual studio 2019. are you asking to post the code that i wrote out for my project?

Comment: Hi John, we typically need to see your code. Can you please edit to show the https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example